# Angular 5 - Looping in the ngOnInit for data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have this data:

```
myData = [
 {
    "name": "namehere"
    "path": "somepath",
    "const": "someconst",
    "method": "somemethod"
    ""
  },
  {
    "name": "othernamehere"
    "path": "othersomepath",
    "const": "othersomeconst",
    "method": "othersomemethod"
    ""
  }
];
```

What I what to do is to create a loop on the ngOnInit so I can do multiple imports dynamically.

It would look something like this with the myData.path etc taken from the data

```
ngOnInit() {

    import(myData.path).then(module => {
      const myData.const = new module.myData.name().myData.method();
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `forEach` function :

```
myData.forEach((data,index) => {
    import(data.path).then(module => {
        this.myData[index].const = new module.data.name().data.method();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can asynchronously import and load modules on demand

```
myData = [
 {
    "name": "namehere"
    "path": "somepath",
    "const": "someconst",
    "method": "somemethod"
    ""
  },
  {
    "name": "othernamehere"
    "path": "othersomepath",
    "const": "othersomeconst",
    "method": "othersomemethod"
    ""
  }
];

myData.map((module)=>{
   import(module.path+'/'+module.name).then(module => {
      // Here you should use an array and assign each module to an array
      // which you can use later to use it's exported methods
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to try the same solution as suggested byt @vivek, but with last ES version approach :

```
for(const [index, data] of Object.entries(myData)) {
  const module = await import(data.path);
  myData[index].const = new module.data.name().data.method();
});
```

Here I use for...of to replace foreach with its callback, and await to replace the promise level of indentation.

Will need async in front of the function :

```
async ngOnInit() {
```

To manage the usage of await in it.

Comment: I'm getting this warning: "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"

Comment: and you are not getting it with the solution of @vivek ?